# Linux ncurses outliner options

Tags: linux, ncurses

I'm looking for a replacement for [hnb](http://hnb.sourceforge.net/), which served me well but seems to be abandoned.

Please do not suggest text-editor based approaches like emacs org mode or vim outliner.

I want a stand-alone tool, preferably written in Python, with ncurses interface (so it could run on Linux with no X server).

Comment: It's not helpful to flat-out rule out reasonable answers like a text-editor. Please explain why you feel that vim-outliner et al are not suitable.

Comment: @sleske: I have excluded those options to make sure people wouldn't suggest me something I've already tried. My goal is not to argue about nice features and drawbacks of particular apps. My goal is to get some suggestions that I've overlooked myself when googling (bad luck with search keywords perhaps). Sometimes I bump into apps that are not very popular but suit me very well, so I've asked here hoping that it'll eventually happen one more time.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. In general it's probably a good idea to mention this in the question (as in "I've tried A, B, C, they are nice, but I'm looking for other solutions to try as well").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I still settled for a vim outline plugin, because I couldn't find a stand-alone small outliner.

I've decided to use [VOoM](http://vim-voom.webs.com/).